# Is a Twilio "from" SMS ID considered secure?

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

If I am receiving SMS messages through Twilio, is it reasonable to assume that I can authenticate the user solely through the phone number used to send it?  Does Twilio perform any sort of spoofing detection?

Comment: I think I'd want to get a bit more detail about what you're trying to do here. Can you expand a bit further?

Comment: @philnash -- really what I am asking is -- how much can I trust the caller ID that comes in with the SMS to identify the user who sent it?  If I preregister a user's phone number, and then ask them to text submissions -- can I match those user's texts to the account and be certain that they are the one that sent it, or is it possible that a bad actor could spoof the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

SMS sender ID spoofing is possible (we don't allow it on the Twilio platform) but it's not something we can detect if it is happening external to us.

It is possible that a bad actor could spoof a number and send to your Twilio number. SMS is not a secure method of communication, so in general I would recommend that you don't respond to incoming messages with sensitive information.

Ultimately, an SMS sender ID cannot intrinsically be totally secure, this doesn't stop it being useful to work with, it's just a risk that needs to be considered and managed.